# Equality of two $\sigma$-algebras on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: measure-theory

I need help with this problem:

Let $p > 1$ a integer, $X = \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$,  $\mathcal{B}$ the borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X$ and $T \colon x \mapsto px \text{ mod } 1$

I think that $$T^{-1}\mathcal{B} = \Sigma :=\{A \in \mathcal{B}\colon \quad A + p^{-1} = A \text{ mod }1\}$$

I know that $T^{-1}A = \bigcup_{k=0}^{p-1} \frac{A + k}{p}$ so $T^{-1}A \in \Sigma$, hence $T^{-1}\mathcal{B} \subseteq \Sigma$, but I don't know how to prove or disprove that $\Sigma \subseteq T^{-1}\mathcal{B}$.

Thanks.